# Show that the following equation has a solution in the interval (-1,1)

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following equation has a solution in the interval (-1,1) 
I think its to do with intermediate value theorem but not sure what to do. 
$$
\frac{e^x - 2}{x - 1} + \frac{e^x - 0.25}{x + 1} = 0
$$

Comment: Well, if you know that you should start with the intermediate value theorem, then maybe you should do exactly what it states. Form a function and then look at the values of the function for the two different values of $x$ ....

Answer (score 3):

The limit as $x \rightarrow -1^+$ (to the right of $-1$) gives you $+\infty$ because of the term $\frac{e^x - 0.25}{x + 1}$, you know that $e^{-1} - 0.25 > 0$ and hence the sign of $\frac{e^x - 0.25}{x + 1}$ would depend on $x+1$ which is positive as $x \rightarrow -1^+$. Similarly, the limit as $x \rightarrow +1^-$ (to the left of $+1$) gives you $-\infty$.

Imagine how the curve would look like, it has to cut the x-axis, unless your function is piecewise continuous, which is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

If calculator is allowed, you can try several numbers from the interval.

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{e^x - 2}{x - 1} + \frac{e^x - 0.25}{x + 1}, x\in (-1,1)$.  It is continuous in its domain.

Now calculate:
$$\begin{align}f(-0.9)&=2.404>0 \ \ \ \ \ (f(0)=1.75>0 \text{ will also do})\\
f(0.9)&=-3.433<0 \end{align}$$
By IVT, there must be a point $c\in (-0.9,0.9)$, for which $f(c)=0$.